# grafana/influxdb display ratio of two fields

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a timeseries measurement stored in influxdb where one column represents the sum and the other represents the count, I want to divide these two columns and plot their ratio in grafana. Something like what is show in the attached screenshot (somehow the points do not show). Additionally over the group by interval I would like to aggregate the max of those ratios

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem as follows:

1. use the manual query editor
2. create a secondary query to calculate the average and then use a primary query to aggregate the results of the secondary one

---

```
 SELECT  max("average") 
    FROM (
           SELECT "sum"/"count"
           AS "average"
           FROM "measurement"
           WHERE ("key" =~ /^$value$/)
         )
    WHERE $timeFilter
    GROUP BY time(15m) fill(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to text edit mode and write query manually (editor is not very UI friendly for more complex queries):

```
SELECT MAX("<sum field>"/"<count field>") 
FROM "<measurement>" 
WHERE $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

Comment: thanks for the tip about the manual query editor however your solution was not correct. I kept getting **expected field argument in max**